# Mathematical problem

Tags: javascript, math, algebra

I have the following function:

```
function getLevel(points)
{
  var level = -1 + Math.sqrt(4 + points/20);

  // Round down to nearest level
  return Math.floor(level);
}
```

The above function calculates the level of a player based on their points, my problem is that I need a function like this to calculate the points needed for a given level.

Comment: Let's start with calculating how many answers you need to accept to raise your acceptance ratio a bit above 20% shall we?

Comment: How long did you try? This should be solvable using high-school level math.

Comment: Ignoring the `Math.floor` (as you should) simplifies things greatly.

Comment: I`m only on the 9th class, we haven`t learn things like these

Comment: By the way: we know it's a math problem because of the 'math' tag. That means you're free to choose a more informative title if you want to.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+L+%3D+-1+%2B+sqrt%284+%2B+P%2F20%29+for+P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Math.sqrt(4 + points/20) =        level + 1

          4 + points/20  =       (level + 1)^2

              points/20  =       (level + 1)^2 - 4

              points     = 20 * ((level + 1)^2 - 4)
                         = 20 * ((level^2 +  2*level + 1) - 4)
                         = 20 * ( level^2 +  2*level - 3     )
                         = 20 *   level^2 + 40*level - 60
```

Comment: thanks, this one worked : points = 20*level * level + 40*level - 60;

Comment: They should all work. Just remember that in javascript, the `^` operator does *not* mean "raise to the power of".

Answer (score 12):

The inverse of that function would be:

```
points = ((level + 1)**2 - 4) * 20
```

(where `**` is the power operator).

Comment: for level 10 it should give 2340 , this gives 3960

Comment: `((10+1)**2-4)*20 = 2340`, so this is correct for that instance (and in general)

Comment: His answer is correct - you've incorrectly applied it most likely.

Answer (score 6):

```
level = -1 + (4 + points / 20) ** 0.5
level + 1 = (4 + points / 20) ** 0.5
(level + 1) ** 2 = 4 + points / 20
(level + 1) ** 2 - 4 = points / 20
20 * ((level + 1) ** 2 - 4) = points
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be fairly easy, just solve for points:

```
               level              = -1 + Math.sqrt(4 + points / 20)
               level + 1          =      Math.sqrt(4 + points / 20)
      Math.pow(level + 1, 2)      =                4 + points / 20
      Math.pow(level + 1, 2) - 4  =                    points / 20
20 * (Math.pow(level + 1, 2) - 4) =                    points
```

So:

```
points = 20 * (Math.pow(level + 1, 2) - 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 20(L+1)<sup>2</sup> - 80